# How to compare Array efficiently in JS or angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I declared two arrays like below in my angular 2 .ts (type script)file.

```
 parentArray:Array<Model> and initialized with  {a,b,c,d}
 modifiedAarray:Array<Model> modified with data {c,e,f,g}
```

by comparing both array how to efficiently find difference between two ?
[ie] finding newly added and already existing elements

Comment: loop them and use indexOf to see if it exists in the other

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var original = ['a','b','c','d'];
var newarray = ['c','e','f','g'];

var addedEls = newarray.filter(function(a){ return original.indexOf(a) < 0; });
var remvdEls = original.filter(function(a){ return newarray.indexOf(a) < 0; });

alert("These were added: "+addedEls.join(","));
alert("These were removed: "+remvdEls.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` and `Observable` :

```
Observable.from(parentArray)
  .filter(item => {
    // Condition here with modifiedAarray
    // IE: return modified.attribute !== item.attribute;
  })
  .subscribe(item => console.log(item));
```